# ASP.NET MVC passing file with ajax.form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass multiple files using ajax.form (asynchronously).

My Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeSkills", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new {id= "UpdateForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

My input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeSkillList[itemP].fileUpload, new { @class = "AddFileClass", type = "file", style = "width:90%", multiple = "multiple", id="uploadInputId"+itemP })
```

My model:

```
public class EmployeeSkillsModel
{
    public int EmployeeSkillId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "error_skill_category_required")]
    [Display(Name = "category", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "error_skill_description_required")]
    [Display(Name = "employee_skill", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "error_skill_level_required")]
    [Display(Name = "skill_knowledge_level", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string KnowledgeLevel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "additional_info", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "attach_document", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public List<string> UploadedFileNames{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "attach_document", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload { get; set; }

}
```

However in my `EmployeeSkills` method `fileUpload` property is null. I know i can move to `Html.BeginForm` but would like to keep my updates asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't posted you AJAX code, which makes it difficult to help you. However, in general, file uploads via AJAX need to be handled in a specific way. The traditional approach of serializing a form to post via AJAX will not work for file uploads. Instead, you must use `FormData`, which is new in HTML5. That also means that file uploads via AJAX only work in browsers that support `FormData`, which currently is pretty much everything except IE 9 and under. If you need to support any of those lesser versions of IE, you'll have to use a different approach involving either a Flash or Java applet.

Assuming you can safely ignore those versions of IE, it's as simple as:

```
$('#MyForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this); // `this` is the form instance
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/handler',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // do something on success
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // do something on error
        }
    });
});
```